# Java RMI client using a C# TcpChannel server

Tags: c#, java, rmi, remoting

Soooo we have this system here that's working as follows:

We have a Java WS that is exposed to the WWW, so our clients can access it from anywhere.

the **Java WS** is just a bridge to a **.NET C# WS** thats sits in our local intranet. The **.NET C# WS** is using a `TcpChannel` client to connect to a **Windows Service** that is listening on a `TcpChannel` so we could invoke it's methods from the **.NET C# WS**

Question is:

I'm looking into eliminating the need for the **.NET C# WS** - which means -
I want to use **Java RMI** to invoke a remote method in the **C# Windows Service**

It is possible to do such a thing? I've been googling alot and found nothing yet.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the windows service host some kind of server which enables RPC.

Some alternatives:

- WCF ServiceHost
- JSON RPC
- XML RPC

Answer (score 2):

Some analysis and suggestion

- [Java RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)  only works between two Java virtual machines (JVMs). Its a protocol that only understood by the JVM.
- So you cannot call a **C#** program using Java RMI.
- As you mentioned that the **Java WS** is just a facade to **.NET C# WS**. 
  -I am not sure why you need to facade a web service! Web service interfaces are platform/technology neutral and your clients should be able to access the  **.NET C# WS** directly.

I assume you are using a standard web services protocol like SOAP.

Comment: I need that facade since I can't expose the .NET C# WS to the wide internet... thanks for your answer